# expression preceding parenthesis of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I'm trying to figure out how to use an unordered map to call methods of a class, but when I do it says "expression preceding parenthesis of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type". Why is this and what can I do to get it to work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Calculator {
public:
    void add(int& n) {
        ++n;
    }

    void sub(int& n) {
        --n;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    std::unordered_map<char, void(Calculator::*)(int&)> umap;
    umap[0] = Calculator::add;
    umap[1] = Calculator::sub;
    int x;
    x = 10;
    umap[0](x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you want pointers to member functions? The functions do not depend on internal state of `Calculator` class, they could be free (or `static` member) functions.

Comment: I felt it would be easier and cleaner if they were in a class, is that not something you can do?

Comment: You need an object of that class to call the function with. Something like `Calculator c; (c.*(umap[0]))[x]`.

Comment: Member functions and non-member functions (e.g. static or at namespace scope) are very different. As written, your `add` and `sub` functions both need a `Calculator` instance on which to call them, which affects the syntax and how you actually call them. Is this really what you want?